# Formatting of detail section in SAP Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using SAP crystal report in WPF and I want formatting (Bold, color) of detail section’s  last record of every  group.

Is this possible, please help.

[image]

Comment: can we make any formula of last record for formatting.

Comment: you can find the index from the section records. and then you can set the formatting on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet in your formatting formulas.

```
onlastrecord //if last record in report then next() will not work
or next({table.group_field}) <> {table.group_field} //the next record starts a new group
```

For example, if you wanted to change the last detail section's background color to yellow in each group, then you would use the formatting formula:

```
if (onlastrecord or next({table.group_field}) <> {table.group_field})
  then cryellow else crnocolor
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter.  If you have Crystal 7.0 or above use the Running Total 
Feature.  If not, then create a running total using formulas. 
Go do a format section.. at the detail line go to the color tab.
Click on the background check box.
Go into the formula section using the box next to the words "Background Color"
Type in:

> If Remainder ("Counter", 5) = 0 then 
>        Yellow 
>     else 
>        White

or you could say NoColor "Counter" in this case is in place of the formula that you are using for the counter.

The row count 5 can be replaced with .

> Count ({Table.Value})